# Can I remove a second install of Mac OS X?

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard, install

I had to get the logic board and HDD replaced on my Unibody MBP, before I sent it back to Apple, I took a DMG copy of my hard drive thinking I could just remount it once I got my MBP back.

When I got it back it had a blank Snow Leopard install, when I tried to restore the backup that I took, I had to create a new partition and mount the DMG to that. So now I've got 2 Mac OS X installs on the MBP.

I changed the default boot partition to my old install so I can use the MBP as it was but I want to put it back to its default behaviour.

Can I just use Time Machine to backup my old Mac OS X install and restore that on the blank Mac OS X install I got when Apple sent my MBP back?

What happens to the second partition I created? Can that be removed?

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done using Carbon Copy Cloner. You can try the following steps.

1. Format the MB HDD as a single partition. Make sure it is a bootable partition.
2. Install OS X using the OS X Installation DVD.
3. Download and install CCC.
4. [Follow these instructions](http://help.bombich.com/kb/dmg-and-remote/dmg-restore) to restore the system partition using CCC.

Answer (score 1):

A similar, alternative method is to go through the aforementioned installation process (starting up from the installation DVD), but use Disk Utility to restore your image. Launch it from the "Utilities" menu in the tool bar. Once it starts up, select your startup disk from the menu on the left and drag it to the "Destination" field. Drag your .dmg to the "Source" field. Click "Restore" at the bottom right and you should be good to go.